# How pancakeswap website find a multi-hop path to trade a coin

Tags: tokens, uniswap, pancakeswap, decentralized-exchange, trading

I publish  tokenA

I add liquidity to  tokenA/usdt

I then want to use my "cake" to get tokenA

Pancakeswap website discover there is no liquidity cake->tokenA, it then could **very intelligently find the path cake->usdt->tokenA** and report the suggested price.

What is the algorithm of pancakeswap website in finding multi hop path?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late reply.

Pancakeswap achieves multihops with Uniswaps V3 router which acts as a wrapper to V2 Router. You can checkout the sources here:

https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol
https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/guides/swaps/multihop-swaps